# Landsat Data to Map Slums in India

Tags: raster, remote-sensing, classification, image, landsat

I am working on a project to answer the following geographic question: How much have slum areas increased in Mumbai, India, since the 1970's (or earliest data).

I have downloaded LandSat imagery and plan to perform a series of raster classifications to map slum areas. I have imagery from 1975 (LandSat 2), 1993 (LandSat 5), and 2014 (LandSat 8).

Is my approach to this question practical given the data I have access too? I feel I can work with my latest data set, but how much accuracy can I classify images from LandSat 2 and 5? I know that the cell size of LandSat 2 is pretty course(60m). I am using ArcGIS software and would like to know how more experienced GIS professionals would approach this?

Comment: Do you mean to use RGB channels of LANDSAT imagery to manualy digitize slums? Please be more specific regarding the methodology you had in mind, if you would like valuable answeres

Comment: At 60 and even 30 meters, differentiating 'slums' from regular neighborhoods will likely prove fairly tough to do. Even at 15m for the new ETM panchromatic seems fairly hopeful. Down in the 5-1m range would be better. I'm not an expert, but in my opinion that data source isn't suitable for the task and I would look into more detailed imagery.

Comment: I agree with ChrisW. I could see distinguishing rural areas from urbanized areas with such imagery, but delineating specifically between slums and a middle class neighborhood would be very difficult. If I were you I would look for non-satellite aerial imagery and then define the rules for what a slum looks like.

Comment: Slums likely have the same spectral signature as all urban areas, although they may have higher building density. How would you differentiate between slums and other urban areas?